# Pre-existing session required for handler method "methodHandlerName"

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I realise my handler "**methodHandlerName**" has an argument **HttpSession session** which is why my spring mvc application throws the error:
*Pre-existing session required for handler method "methodHandlerName"*

But where in my application would I have to set a session. I presume there's no session in my application is it's set to false by default; and would to set it somewhere in my application context.

thanks

Comment: give more of the stacktrace and your web.xml

Comment: Sorry, it's resolved, I realize I had an include directive; and in the include file, session was set to false.

Comment: Nice work Terman. As a friendly reminder, can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.